# How to convert one str element from tuple to int value?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a tuple contains name, symbol, and number,
for example:

```
('albus dumbledore', '>', '3')
```

and I was trying to compare the number and other integer value from a list and I got an error message said **'>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'**.
So I think I think I need to change the number value from the tuple from *str* to *int* like the below

```
('albus Dumbledore, '>', 3)
```

how do I convert the value?

Comment: Please update your question with your actual code and the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a tuple is created, you cannot change its values. You must first convert it into a regular list with `list()`, change its values, then convert it back to a tuple with `tuple()`. In order to convert a string into an integer, you can try to use `int()`, then ignore the items that cannot be converted into an integer:

```py
tuple_list = ('albus dumbledore', '>', '3')

tuple_list_modified = list(tuple_list)
for i in range(len(tuple_list_modified)):
    try:
        tuple_list_modified[i] = int(tuple_list_modified[i])
    except ValueError:
        continue

tuple_list = tuple(tuple_list_modified)
print(tuple_list)
```

Output:

```
('albus dumbledore', '>', 3)
```